# Common segment of longest paths in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I came across a programming questions where one will be

1. given a weighted tree.
2. Set of nodes one is interested in, let us call this set S.

We need to return the shortest of the common segment of the longest of the ideal paths.
ideal path is the path that starts and terminates on a vertex that belongs to set S above.
It is n't assured that the common path exists.
I am aware of finding the longest path in a tree in linear time and also we can easily extend it to the case of ideal paths, but the classical algorithm of 2 dfs's, is not going to help in
finding the longest paths, but just the longest path lengths.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

1. Path begin
2. Path length, got from algorithm like DFS or BFS
3. Path end

You can easily get path.
Change code:

```
//current vertex is v, next is u, current length is l
u.length = l + 1;
u.visited = true;
cont.push(u);
```

Adding line:

```
u.previous = v;
```

Then you can find path by:

```
v = path_end;
while(v != path_begin){
    //mark, v belongs to "path"
    v = v.previous
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it is a weighted tree and also there can be many longest paths, the main task is to get all those paths.